# Need help on this line of reasoning

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

I am reading Bromwich's Introduction to the theory of infinite series 2nd edition (1926) and get stuck here. The lines that causes confusion is marked in red.

For example

$|a_n-l|<f(n,m),$ when $n>m$

What is $f(n,m)$ here means? Is it a function of two variables?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means.

Comment: Then what does $|a_n-l|<f(n,m)$ mean? One is the limit of the sequence $a_n$, the other is a function of two variables. What do they have to do with one another?

Comment: It means that the difference between a sum and the limit of the sums is less than some function defined in terms of n, where n is the number of terms in the sum, and m is some other variable.

Comment: $f$ is a function; $f(m,n)$ is a number just like $|a_n-l|$.

Comment: I have been rereading this section and still can't follow the argument.